# In need of a Rogue web server

Tags: test-tools, server, tool-recommend

I am trying to test a http proxy, and how it will behave with it receives rogue http responses.
I am looking for a webserver, preferably open-sourced, which I can used to send rogue http responses, example, a http response with content-size set to 0 but has content, etc.
In past I had used Codenomicon tool, which is a paid one. I am looking for an open-source alternative.
Any ideas are welcome.

Comment: What research have you done and what options have you found?

Comment: Hi Kate. I did a lot of search on google and so far have'nt found anything good. I my previous organisation we used "Defensics's tool' which did a lot of fuzzing on server side. I am looking for open source tools.

Comment: This is what I had used earlier. https://www.synopsys.com/software-integrity/security-testing/fuzz-testing/defensics/protocols/http-client.html